# Covariance of $X^2$ and $X^3$ when $X$ is exponentially distributed

Tags: probability, covariance

Here is my work....

$\begin{align*} 
Cov(Y,Z) &= E(YZ) - E(Y)E(Z)\\
&= E(X^2\cdot X^3) - E(X^2)E(X^3)\\
&= E(X^5) - E(X^2)E(X^3)
\end{align*}$

And we know $E(X^n) = \frac{n!}{\lambda^n}$ so,

$\begin{align*} 
Cov(Y,Z) &= \frac{5!}{\lambda^5} - \frac{2!}{\lambda^2}\cdot \frac{3!}{\lambda^3}\\
&= \frac{120}{\lambda^5} - \frac{12}{\lambda^5}\\
&= \frac{108}{\lambda^5}
\end{align*}$

Does this seem like it is correct? Thanks!

Comment: It looks fine. Perhaps you are expected to do the integrations explicitly, or use the mgf.

Comment: $2!\cdot 3!$ is $12$

Comment: @NarutSereewattanawoot whoops thanks!

Comment: Yes, but the final result is OK, so it's a typo.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Ya this seems extremely simple, so maybe more work is wanted

Comment: If you prove the equation $${\rm E}[X^n] = n!/\lambda^n,$$ then your solution should be completely satisfactory as stated.  You could do it with an MGF but it is just as valid to do the integration directly and appeal to the gamma function or gamma distribution.

Comment: @heropup Awesome thanks! I will include that in my final work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer looks right, though maybe you want to prove the identity $E(x^n) = {n! \over \lambda^n}$. If you want a funky proof (assuming x ~ $\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$):

$$
E(x^n) = \lambda \int^\infty_0 x^n e^{- \lambda x} dx \\
= \lambda \int^\infty_0 \left((-1)^n {d^n \over d \lambda^n} e^{-\lambda x} \right) dx\\
= (-1)^n \lambda {d^n \over d \lambda^n} \int^\infty_0 e^{-\lambda x} dx \\
= (-1)^n \lambda {d^n \over d \lambda^n} {1 \over \lambda} \\
= {n! \over \lambda^n}
$$

The third line follows from the second because integration over x and differentiation WRT $\lambda$ is commutative.

Comment: 1. What does $\frac{d^n}{d\lambda ^n}e^{- \lambda x}$ mean ? It is the nth differentiation of $e^{- \lambda x}$ w.r.t $\lambda ? \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $ 2. And what is the relation between first line and the second line ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it means the nth derivative WRT $\lambda$. The second line follows from the first line simply by
$\frac{d^n}{d \lambda^n} e^{-\lambda x} = (-1)^n x^n e^{-\lambda x}$.

Comment: Now I've got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct.

If you try the R code

```
set.seed(2014)
cases  <- 1000000
lambda <- 10
X      <- rexp(cases, lambda)
cov(X^2, X^3)
```

you get $0.001079931$ which is closer to $\dfrac{108}{10^5}$ than you have any reasonable right to expect